# How to use schtasks to query a remote server as a non-admin?

Tags: task-scheduler, schtasks

I want to query a remote server's tasks:

```
schtasks /query /s <server-name>
ERROR: Access is denied.
```

The account I am running this from is not a local admin on the remote server, but I have the following set up:

- The account has read and execute permissions to C:\Windows\System32\Tasks on the remote server (as per "[allow-to-view-and-run-scheduled-tasks-without-admin-rights](https://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/clients/576-allow-to-view-and-run-scheduled-tasks-without-admin-rights)")
- The account has the following user rights assignment set on local security policy on the remote server (these were chosen using an answer given [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/89c26f79-8792-4ff8-a839-7783adc3ec55/what-permission-is-required-for-running-the-schedule-task-for-that-account?forum=winserverDS), although I kept adding to it to try and get it to work):

  - Allow log on locally
  - Backup files and directories
  - Log on as a batch job
  - Log on as a service
  - Manage auditing and security log
  - Generate Security Audit

It is not a firewall issue as an admin account can remote into the server and run the query.

All other similar issues I've seen are to do with how to run a task without being a local admin on the remote server. I only want to query the tasks as a non-admin.

Comment: FWIW, if you're giving an account "backup files and directories" privilege, you may as well make it local admin - there's no real difference.  I don't *think* there's any built-in way to configure Windows to allow a non-admin to query the scheduled tasks remotely, but there might be third-party tools.

Comment: I see. I ended up going to each individual machine and importing a scheduled task to run a powershell script that queries what tasks are on that machine. Not ideal since we'd rather just iterate through an arbitrary list of servers and fetch a list of tasks on each one. Either way, it works.